# Go to random frame, excluding current frame

Tags: javascript, random, animate-cc

Here is my problem.

My main timeline has 3 frames. Each frame contains different movieClip.

**I created a button, and when user clicks this button, I want a random movieclip to play.**

**But, I don't want to play the same movieClip again.** So, when user is on the frame 1 and clicks the button, either frame 2 or 3 should play. Similarly, if the user is on the frame 2, frame 1 or 3 should play.

Now, I used this code and almost achieved what I wanted:

```js
var _this = this;
_this.Play_button.on('click', function(){
_this.gotoAndStop(0+Math.random()*2);
});
```

But. Many times, the click on the button goes to the same frame, and this is not what I want.

Could someone here help me to achieve this? This is a HTML5 canvas, if it makes a difference.

Comment: I would store the current frame ID and when you calculate the new frame ID I would compare it to the stored one. Do this in a Do While loop.

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for you?

```
var _this = this;
var _lastFrameID = -1; //set default value for last frame ID
_this.Play_button.on('click', function(){
    let frameID = -1; //set default value for current frame ID
    do {
        frameID = Math.random()* 2; //do calculation for new frame ID
    }
    while(frameID === _lastFrameID); //check if they are the same, if they are repeat calculation
    _lastFrameID = frameID; //set current frame ID to the last frame ID
    _this.gotoAndStop(frameID); //call your function with new frame ID
});
```

Comment: Hey and thank you for taking a time to answer. I tried your solution but unfortunately it didn't work. Please take into account I am working with Animate CC, could that be an issue?

Comment: Thing is, I can't really test your code. All I'm doing is providing something like a pseudo code here... The basic idea is to store the current frame ID into memory, and then compare the new frame ID with the stored one until you get a different value than you already have. Then overwrite the last frame ID with the new value.

Comment: Updated my anwser with comments

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I will do my best to make it work.